# Loop and add with 2 lists

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, for-loop

I have two lists in the next code snippet:

```
lst1 = ['a','b','c','d']
lst2 = [1,2,3,4]
```

I'm willing to loop over the second list while using the first and get the following:

```
'a','b','c','d'
'a','b',1,'c','d'
'a','b',1,2,'c','d'
'a','b',1,2,3,'c','d'
'a','b',1,2,3,4,'c','d'
```

how am I able to do this using a for loop?

Thanks

Comment: Just to be sure: your 'lst' indexation start from 1, is it intentional?

Comment: What should be the result if the first list is `['a', 'b', 'c']` and the second list is `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`?

Comment: same as I wrote but until 6. I mean ab12345cd, ab123456cd..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot of funny slice syntax, pretty straightforward. Probably some boundary condition (odd count of l1) should be verified.

```
def yield_from_l1_l2(l1, l2):
    HALF_OF_L1 = len(l1) / 2
    for i in xrange(len(l2)+1):
        yield l1[:HALF_OF_L1] + l2[:i] + l1[HALF_OF_L1:]

l1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
l2 = [1, 2, 3, 4]

for l in yield_from_l1_l2(l1, l2):
    print l
```

Output:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
['a', 'b', 1, 'c', 'd']
['a', 'b', 1, 2, 'c', 'd']
['a', 'b', 1, 2, 3, 'c', 'd']
['a', 'b', 1, 2, 3, 4, 'c', 'd']
```

Comment: Hi, i have tried this and I get --> "Can only concatenate list (not "str") to list". Why is this happening

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking isn't absolutely clear; do you want something like that:

```
for i in range(len(b)+1):
  tmp = []
  for j in range(len(a)):
    if j==2:
      tmp += b[:i]
    tmp.append( a[j] )
  print tmp
```

or better:

```
for i in range(len(b)+1):
  print a[:2] + b[:i] + a[2:]
```

Comment: Second one is simple and small.

Answer (score 1):

Damn, beaten by the bell.
The following is a short-cut, it will not iterate over the list in the way you'd want it to (making it a bit faster). use this is possible:

```
list1 = ['a','b','c','d']
list2 = [1,2,3,4]
list1 = list1[:2] + list2 + list1[2:]
```

If you need to iterate over the list, and you want to preserve lines of code as well as memory usage, iterate over the second list and just add it within the first list:

```
a = ['a','b','c','d']
b = [1,2,3,4]
for i in range(0, len(b)-1):
    a = a[:2+i] + [b[i]] + a[-2:]
```

The results will be:

```
['a', 'b', 1, 2, 3, 'c', 'd']
```

Comment: Hey, I have to iterate. I used the the second you wrote and I get "list index out of range".. also incorrect output..

Comment: @pugilon i see, well i pasted my exact code into my console and it works flawlessly, since you have accepted another answer i will not bother trying to figure out why you get the error you mention since you'll most likely move away further from this solution by the time i investigate. Thank you never the less for taking the time to reply :)